# Python `with` context vs generators/coroutines/tasks

Tags: python, coroutine

I want to experiment with using python `with` blocks to apply modifiers to action within that block. But I'm not sure if it's possible to do this sensibly in the presence of coroutines.

For example, suppose I have a `WithContext` object that temporarily pushes onto a stack like this:

```py
class WithContext:
    stack = []
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __enter__(self):
        WithContext.stack.append(self.val)
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        WithContext.stack.pop()
def do_scoped_contextual_thing():
    print(WithContext.stack[-1])
```

(Obviously the stack member would have to be thread-local, but ignore that for now.)

Then this code:

```
with WithContext("a"):
    do_scoped_contextual_thing()
    with WithContext("b"):
        do_scoped_contextual_thing()
with WithContext("c"):
   do_scoped_contextual_thing()
```

Will print:

```
a
b
c
```

But now suppose I have a coroutine situation:

```py
def coroutine():
    with WithContext("inside"):
        yield 1
        do_scoped_contextual_thing()
        yield 2

with WithContext("outside"):
    for e in coroutine():
        do_scoped_contextual_thing()
        print("got " + str(e))
```

I *want* this code to output:

```
outside
got 1
inside
outside
got 2
```

But actually it will output:

```
inside
got 1
inside
inside
got 2
```

The outsides changed to insides because the `__enter__` inside the coroutine put a value on top of the stack, and `__exit__` isn't called until the coroutine ends (instead of constantly enter-ing and exit-ing as you bounce in and out of the coroutine).

Is there a way to work around this problem? Are there "coroutine-local" variables?

Comment: Don’t have global mutable state (`WithContext.stack` here); pass it in instead. `for e in coroutine(stack): do_scoped_contextual_thing(stack)` where `stack` is immutable.

Comment: Have you considered an accessor on the result of the context? Something like `with WithContext('outside') as outside:` ... `outside.do_scoped_contextual_thing()` ?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, I'm aware of the downsides. I still want to experiment with it.

Comment: Well, this isn’t possible otherwise, so that was the alternative…

Comment: @AustinHastings That would defeat the purpose. The goal of the experiment is to avoid passing a common context object into every single method. Packing the context into an object still requires passing it around, so I'd just avoid the with block altogether if I was going to do that.

Comment: @Ryan If you can point at docs explaining that it's not possible, that's a reasonable answer to the question.

Comment: I'll note, @AustinHastings's suggestion is how Python already deals with this. The `decimal` module does allow for `with` scoped context (based on thread locals, so each thread has its own context stack), but also makes most (all?) of its API available from the context objects themselves, so you can explicitly use a specific context without replacing the thread's current context. The solution here would be to use your `with` stuff for non-coroutine use, while the coroutines use local state that explicitly references their own context.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel great about this, but I did modify your test code to re-enter the coroutine a few times. Similar to @CraigGidney's solution, this uses the `inspect` module to access and cache information on the call stack (aka, the "scope") in which a `WithContext` object is created.

I then basically search up the stack looking for a cached value, and use the `id` function to try and avoid holding references to the actual frame objects.

```
import inspect

class WithContext:
    stack = []
    frame_to_stack = {}
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __enter__(self):
        stk = inspect.stack(context=3)
        caller_id = id(stk[1].frame)
        WithContext.frame_to_stack[caller_id] = len(WithContext.stack)
        WithContext.stack.append( (caller_id, self.val))

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        wc = WithContext.stack.pop()
        del WithContext.frame_to_stack[wc[0]]

def do_scoped_contextual_thing():
    stack = inspect.stack(context=0)
    f2s = WithContext.frame_to_stack

    for f in stack:
        wcx = f2s.get(id(f.frame))

        if wcx is not None:
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError("No context object in scope.")

    print(WithContext.stack[wcx][1])

def coroutine():
    with WithContext("inside"):
        for n in range(3):
            yield 1
            do_scoped_contextual_thing()
            yield 2

with WithContext("outside"):
    for e in coroutine():
        do_scoped_contextual_thing()
        print("got " + str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible half-broken "solution" is to associate the context with a stack frame's location, and check for that location when looking up the context.

```py
class WithContext:
    _stacks = defaultdict(list)

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __enter__(self):
        _, file, _, method, _, _ = inspect.stack()[1]
        WithContext._stacks[(file, method)].append(self.val)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        _, file, _, method, _, _ = inspect.stack()[1]
        WithContext._stacks[(file, method)].pop()

    @staticmethod
    def get_context():
        for frame in inspect.stack()[1:]:
            _, file, _, method, _, _ = frame
            r = WithContext._stacks[(file, method)]
            if r:
                return r[-1]
        raise ValueError("no context")
```

Note that constantly looking up stack frames is more expensive than just passing values around, and that you may not want to tell people you wrote this.

**Note that this will still break in more complicated situations.**

For example:

- What if the same method is on the stack twice?
- What if the generator is iterated a bit from one place, then a bit more from another place?
- What about recursive generators?
- What about async methods?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Esentially I wanted to be able to execute code upon entering/leaving the running context of a coroutine, in my case to keep a call stack of sorts that is correct even in the case of interleaved `yield`s.  It turns out [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) has support for this in the form of a [StackContext](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/stack_context.html) which can be used as follows:

```
@gen.coroutine
def correct():
    yield run_with_stack_context(StackContext(ctx), other_coroutine)
```

where `ctx` is a context manager that will `enter` and `exit` while the event loop is executing `other_coroutine`.

See https://github.com/muhrin/plumpy/blob/8d6cd97d8b521e42f124e77b08bb34c8375cd1b8/plumpy/processes.py#L467 for how I use it.

I've not looked into the implementation but tornado v5 switched to using `asyncio` as their default event loop so it should be compatible with that too.